# Radio button if one is checked the other should be unchecked

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a radio group in my project how do I uncheck all before start and how do I uncheck one if the other is checked. When I clicked on the other button it does not unchecked the other one and I cant figure out how to deal with it I cant even get the index of this buttons I mean I can get the value of the text box I got the code on a tutorial side but sadly it does not explain its code clearly

code is

```
<RadioGroup
   android:id="@+id/radioGender"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         
   <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/genderMale"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Male"
      android:checked="true" />

   <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/genderFemale"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Female" />
        
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Have a Look at  `RadioGroup` http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

Comment: i cant understand this private RadioButton radioSexButton; i cant see where it is same tutorial but not the same site

Comment: radioSexButton is a class level RadioButton created to hold the ID of the selected RadioButton in the tutorial. It doesn't repressent any of the two RadioButton created in the xml file but holds their ID in run time i.e. on button click. Also if you want to have all the RadioButton as unchecked initially set *android:checked="false"* for all of them. (Default is also false but I am not sure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the radiobuttons to a radiogroup

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="One" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Two" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: can i put each radio button on a separate linear layout inside the radiogroup?

Comment: i have a question does it have something to do with the java when i run my xml with separate linearlayout so i can have them evenly side by side they dont uncheck each other but when i remove the linear layout they uncheck each other

Comment: All the radiobuttons inside a radiogroup will in same child level. So there is no code needed in Java to uncheck other radiobuttons when one radiobutton is checked.

Comment: sir please check the paste bin

Answer (score 3):

to uncheck all radio button:

```
RadioButtonGroup rgButton = (RadioButtonGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiobuttongroup);
rgButton.clearCheck();
```

if radio buttons are in the same radio group, so automatically when you check one the other will be unchecked.

to check if a radio box is checked or not:

```
if(rb.isChecked()==true)
```

Answer (score 1):

i come across this question while i was looking for another problem but it's good to share knowledge ,i encountered the same issue a time ago ,
any one facing this problem don't forget to add an ***@+id*** for each RadioButton 
good luck ninjas.

Comment: This answer does not provide any extra information which has already not been covered in the accepted answer.

Comment: helpful for the case when adding the RadioButton to RadioGroup manually.

Comment: It adds because the @+id wasn't explicitly mentioned and without it defined, if you have more layout elements inside the RadioGroup and checks a radio button, the other don't get unchecked.